# I overstayed in Spain with residence visa, but again received a new residence visa. Can I enter Spain?

Tags: schengen, spain, overstaying, denial-of-entry, visa-bans

I had a residence permit in Spain but I overstayed for several months after the residence period expires. While departing Spain, the immigration officer took a photo of my passport and verbally warned me (with visible disappointment) about entry ban for 5 or 10 years.

But they did not give me any document or did not put anything in my passport. They took a photo of my passport and let me leave. Probably because it was a voluntary leave. During my overstay, I also did not receive any letter to leave Spain, nor received a fine, nor stopped by the Police.

A few months later, I received a Spanish residence permit of 3 years, issued by the Spanish government to conduct research in Spain in a research institute. During the residence permit application, the Spanish government asked for a proof of exit from Spain, and proof of living in my home country, as they were not sure enough that I left Spain.

I provided copies of my passport with an exit stamp from Spain and entry stamp from my home country. Upon receiving this proof, they very promptly issued a residence permit (probably because of the category of residence).

Upon getting the residence permit resolution letter from the Spanish government, I applied for a visa at the Spanish consulate in my home country. I had to collect and submit the criminal record certificate from Spain (which says no criminal activities recorded against me in Spain, surprisingly, as I expected that it might include the 5- or 10-year ban due to my overstay in Spain) during the visa application. Note that I had a new passport when I applied for the visa and criminal record, because my old passport was expired.

My visa has been approved (very promptly) and it has 1 year of validity.

Now, I am concerned. Will there be any problem while entering Spain at the airport? Is there any chance of getting entry denied, despite having a visa?

Comment: It's very unlikely that the passport inspector at the border will have access to more information than the visa officer who decided to grant your visa.

Comment: I think they have access to SIS database, from where my overstay and related ban info might be found easily.

Comment: And so did those granting the visa…

Comment: Then, why the visa was granted? Without checking any previous record? Or, the immigration police did not record my overstay and entry ban n SIS?

Comment: It sounds to me as if all this happened within a relatively short time frame. Could it be that the Spanish justice system needs some time to process the report from the exit immigration check and issue an entry ban and that the ban had not yet been imposed when your new visa was issued?

Comment: I left Spain in January 2023, I applied residence permit in May and the resolution was issued in May, I applied for Visa in September, and the visa was granted in October.

Comment: Did you tell them about the overstay in your visa application?

Comment: No. But I gave document of my residence card (where expiry date is there) and pages of passport where my exit stamps were there. And I also gave the police clearance certificate from Spanish police, where no criminal records were recorded against me in Spain and even in Schengen.